# GitLab all repository ssh clone url shows wrong path

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, centos6, gitlab-omnibus

GitLab Web all repository SSH clone URL shows wrong path.

**Wrong path:** `ssh://git@ssh.gitlab.domain.com:443/test_group/test30-jan-2020.git`

**After modified With following command able to clone on terminal.**

```
git clone git@gitlab.domain.com:test_group/test30-jan-2020.git
```

To correct the same Under Admin--> Settings---> couldn't find option to change it to proper clone url. Any workaround will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kenster, Yes I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be, as documented in "[Configuring the external URL for GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab)" in `external_url` or your `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

Check first  `Admin Area > Settings > General > Sign-in restrictions`

Or, for omnibus, in [`gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/blob/438bf6dffe9029fd06188f6e646bf5454dc05cf2/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template#L29).

The [OP Kishore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4948798/kishore) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224989/gitlab-all-repository-ssh-clone-url-shows-wrong-path/60256419?noredirect=1#comment106593656_60256419):

> In `/etc/gitlab.rb` file, `Gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] =` was enabled.
>   **I have disabled and restarted. It is showing correct path.**

(You could see that setting used in [`sameersbn/docker-gitlab` issue 38](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/issues/38#issuecomment-39640106) )

Comment: Thanks VonC,  In /etc/gitlab.rb file. Gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = was enabled. I have disabled and restarted. It is showing correct path.

Comment: @Kishore Great! Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.